# Upload .env environment variables to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services

As far as I know the only way to set environment variables to elastic beanstalk is either:

1. The AWS Online Console.
2. The `eb setenv` command.

I have a `.env` file in my project that contains all of my environment variables over 100 variables and I'm looking for a way to push them all to the eb instance at the same time.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First off, you should note that Elastic Beanstalk has a limit of fifty (50) environment variables per environment.

Now, if you've got a bunch of environment variables set in a .env file, an easy way to set them en-mass is to just dump them all into the eb setenv command like this...

```
eb setenv `cat .env | sed '/^#/ d' | sed '/^$/ d'`
```

This will set them all in one shot and save you spending all night on the aws console page. The `sed` command remove commented lines and new lines.

[Explain Shell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat+.env+%7C+sed+%27%2F%5E%23%2F+d%27+%7C+sed+%27%2F%5E%24%2F+d%27)

Comment: you need to specify an enviornment for this after eb?

Comment: @omar you can run $ eb use <your env name> and then run the above answer

Comment: hmm..i'm disappointed with myself after 3 days trying to figure out why my environment keeps failing.....and here it is `First off, you should note that Elastic Beanstalk has a limit of fifty (50) environment variables per environment.` Where in the jungle did you find that info @MattCrampton?

Comment: Adding to that...the error I got was `(Namespace: 'aws:cloudformation:template:parameter', OptionName: 'EnvironmentVariables'): Not a List of Key/Value pairs.` HmmmmmmmmmmmAWS

Comment: Just a note, if an env value has characters <> then aws may fail with `ERROR: InvalidSyntaxError - You must use the format KEY=VALUE to set an environment variable. Variables must start with a letter.`

Comment: From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console): "The combined size of all environment properties cannot exceed 4,096 bytes when stored as strings with the format `key=value`."

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning, personally I had a `deploy.sh` script which was doing `npm install`, `npm build`, etc.

So, in a `.ebextensions/example.config` file, I put the following:

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    HealthCheckPath: /health

  # This must be at the end of the file
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    # Will be populated by the deployment script
```

And in my script I have something like this:

```sh
sed -r 's/^([_[:alnum:]]+)=/    \1: /g' .env >> dist/.ebextensions/example.config
```

This `sed` command replaces `^[_\w]+=` with     `$1:` so that all my environment variables are passed in a config file. Thanks to this, I don't have to:

1. Use `eb setenv`
2. Wait for the update to process
3. Use `eb deploy`

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer

```bash
env | while IFS= read -r line; do key=$(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f1); value=$(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f2-); eb setenv $key="$value"; done
```