# Include sensitive environment variables to AWS EB Django app

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a django app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and initially I am defining my environment variable in `.ebextensions/django.config`

Some of those variable are sensitive and I don't want to push them to Git, so I want to encapsulate those variables in a single file (for example: .env) that will not be pushed to Git.

## Plan A:

A way to include .env in my config file, but I didn't find a way to do it supposedly like:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    include .env
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: mydjangoapp.wsgi:application
```

**Cons:**

- The environment variables are shown as plain text in AWS console at *`Elastic Beanstalk > Environments > my-environment > Configuration > Environment properties`*, although I know the fact that they are only readable by the authorised AWS users who have permission to it.

**Pros:**

- Ability to update only and directly the environment variables from AWS console without requiring new deployment.

## Plan B:

Nearly same as plan A, but without including .env file in config file. It is by using `eb setenv` to set the sensitive environments, but it is should be typed explicitly one-by-one, not from an external file, so it is headache if they are a lot

## Plan C:

Remove the sensitive variables at all from my config file and load the .env file from my django app itself.

**Cons:**

- If I want to update any of those variables, I have to deploy a new version of my application.
- Although .env file will not pushed to Git and it can be shared between developers internally, it should be pushed with the deployment package and it will appear in the application ec2 instance directory.

**Pros:**

- Hide sensitive information even from the AWS console

## Questions:

- Is plan A applicable by any means? I could do the same in google cloud app engine yaml files, but I could not find a way to do it in AWS EB configurations https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/beanstalk-environment-configuration-advanced.html
- What is the best practice here? Is there another plan to do?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding plan B - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44914519/12956689) shows a great way to dump all vars from a .env into the `eb setenv ...` command!