# Settings.py: environment variables -> `getenv` or `environ`. What's better? What's the best approach to be able to, also, see my project locally?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-settings

I have one project in production on **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**. In my **settings.py** I'm using [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv), so I'm able to get my environment variables from **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** environment properties. I wonder how can I set my project in such a way, that it can be served as it is by **AWS**, but in meantime, be able to run it locally? *I have set my **PostgreSQL DB** properly on **AWS** so I'm able to use it locally via shell.* The main problem is related to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Should I stick to [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv), or maybe to [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)?

At this moment it is - badly - written, like that:

```
from os import getenv

# ......

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    getenv("APP_HOST", "127.0.0.1")
]
```

Should I add "127.0.0.1" to **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** environment properties? Or should I have my local IP in some file, inside my project? In a file that I won't deploy to **EB**?

Answer (score 0):

To load environment variables locally.

Install:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Make a .env file   where settings.py is.

Add variables to .env.

```
SECRET_KEY=<secret key>
DEBUG=True
```

Add this to setting.py:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Do not upload .env

os.getenv() is similar to os.environ.get()
If key not found it will not raise error, while os.environ[""] will throw keyError.

Comment: In this approach, can I provide my environment variables to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment properties? If so, would it work in such a way that in production it will use AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment properties and locally it will use the `.env` file?

Comment: You can you this code in production settings.py, but make sure you don't upload the .env file to server. On server dotenv will use environment variables normally like before, and on local machine it will load it from .env. See this post for importing .env to AWS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414973/upload-env-environment-variables-to-elastic-beanstalk